# Scrolling Page with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

New to javascript, trying to create a simple program that scrolls to the div when navigation item is clicked. However, its not working, I can't figure out why.

Here is the snippet :

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("asda");
    
      setBindings();
    });
    
    function setBindings() {
      $("nav a").click(function(e) {
         // stops the a tags for working.. i.e. clicking to another page. Functions stops the functionality.
        var sectionID = e.currentTarget.id + "Section";
        alert('button id ' + sectionID);
    
        $("html body").animate({
          scrollTop: $("#" + sectionID).offset().top
        }, 1000)
        })
    
      })
    }
```

```html
<nav class="clearfix">
   <div class="logo-container">
    <i><h2><b>DELIVERY MOTION</b></h2></i>

   </div>

   <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a id="delivery" href="#">Delivery</a></li>
    <li><a  id="about" href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>

   </ul>



   <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
  </nav>


    <div id="deliverySection">
  <h1> Order anything from anywhere in Karachi instantly at your doorstep. </h1><hr>
  <div id='fee-estimate-box'>
   <form id='fee-estimate-form' action="#">
     <legend id='delivery-text'>Delivery Fee Calculator</legend>
     <span>FROM </span> <input type="text" name="firstname" value="PICKUP ADDRESS">
     <span>TO </span> <input type="text" name="lastname" value="DROP ADDRESS">
     <span>ESTIMATED FEE </span> <input type="text" name="estimated-fee" value="0.00 PKR">
     <input class='btn-submit' type="submit" value="BOOK NOW!">
   </form>

  </div>
  <div id='silver-bar'>
   <img src='img/red-car.png' alt='fast deliver'>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="aboutSection">
  <h2> How it works </h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="infobox">
     <img src='img/map-icon.png' width="50px" height="50px">
     <h3> Search </h3>
     <h4>Select pickup address </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
     <br><br>
     <img src='img/arrow-up.png' width="50px" height="50px" class='arrows-img'>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"  id="infobox">
     <img src='img/delivery-icon.png' width="50px" height="50px" class="order-icon-img">
     <h3> Order</h3>
     <h4>Make a booking online </h4>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
     <br>
     <img src='img/arrow-down.png' width="50px" height="50px" class='arrows-img'>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"  id="infobox">
     <img src='img/truck-icon.png' width="50px" height="50px">
     <h3> Delivered</h3>
     <h4>Instant courier delivery</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

At first I thought the problem was with my jquery, however its working fine. The links to javascript is correct too. I've tried rechecking the animate function but I can't pin point the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: There should be a comma between `html` and `body` in your `setBindings()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$("html body") has to be replaced by $("html,body") for the scroll to trigger.
You also had an error in your javascript, one more '})'at the end.
Now that's fine. Check your console for such errors, or use snippets, as in your question.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //  alert("asda");
    
        setBindings();
    });
    
    function setBindings() {
        $("nav a").click(function(e) {
  
        var sectionID = e.currentTarget.id + "Section";
       // alert('button id ' + sectionID+ $("#" + sectionID).offset().top);
    
        $("html,body").animate({
          scrollTop: $("#" + sectionID).offset().top
        }, 1000);
        })
    
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="clearfix">
   <div class="logo-container">
    <i><h2><b>DELIVERY MOTION</b></h2></i>

   </div>

   <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a id="delivery" href="javascript:;">Delivery</a></li>
    <li><a  id="about" href="javascript:;">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:;">Contact</a></li>

    <li><a href="javascript:;/">Login</a></li>

   </ul>



   <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
  </nav>


    <div id="deliverySection">
  <h1> Order anything from anywhere in Karachi instantly at your doorstep. </h1><hr>
  <div id='fee-estimate-box'>
   <form id='fee-estimate-form' action="#">
     <legend id='delivery-text'>Delivery Fee Calculator</legend>
     <span>FROM </span> <input type="text" name="firstname" value="PICKUP ADDRESS">
     <span>TO </span> <input type="text" name="lastname" value="DROP ADDRESS">
     <span>ESTIMATED FEE </span> <input type="text" name="estimated-fee" value="0.00 PKR">
     <input class='btn-submit' type="submit" value="BOOK NOW!">
   </form>

  </div>
  <div id='silver-bar'>
   <img src='img/red-car.png' alt='fast deliver'>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="aboutSection">
  <h2> How it works </h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="infobox">
     <img src='img/map-icon.png' width="50px" height="50px">
     <h3> Search </h3>
     <h4>Select pickup address </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
     <br><br>
     <img src='img/arrow-up.png' width="50px" height="50px" class='arrows-img'>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"  id="infobox">
     <img src='img/delivery-icon.png' width="50px" height="50px" class="order-icon-img">
     <h3> Order</h3>
     <h4>Make a booking online </h4>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
     <br>
     <img src='img/arrow-down.png' width="50px" height="50px" class='arrows-img'>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"  id="infobox">
     <img src='img/truck-icon.png' width="50px" height="50px">
     <h3> Delivered</h3>
     <h4>Instant courier delivery</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I've realised that once I click on about section it scrolls, but when I click the about section again it doesn't work. I have to remove the # in the address bar then it works... Can you please tell me why? i.e. /DM8/index.html# <-- –

Comment: "#" at the end of an url is an anchor. It tell the browser scroll up max, and can be added via a link like this : `<a href="#">Top</a>`
Anchors can also reffer to element's id, so the browser scroll to this element.

Comment: It would have been a REALLY easiest way for doing what you are doing, if your case has no further complication that require javascript.
See the new answer.

Comment: So how do I go about removing the anchor without having to delete the # from the address bar myself everytime?

Comment: Remove # from the href attribute of your links. As href can't be empty, use `href="javascript:;"` in replacement of `href="#"`

Comment: Okay, when I click about us once, then deliver, it works... But if I clicked about again it would not work.

Comment: Solved this : the animate wasn't trigerring,  $("html body") has to be replaced by  $("html,body")

Comment: Ah, for some reason another js function below it was causing the problem. Its works! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, for the scrolling.

```
$('#your_image_for_the_scroll').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
    });
```

This image could appear after user does scroll down a bit:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 20) {        // If page is scrolled more than 20px
            $('#your_image_for_the_scroll').fadeIn(200);
        } else {
            $('#your_image_for_the_scroll').fadeOut(200);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it is because of the typo. There is an extra `)` & `}` at the end of the function

I Have created a [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8g3oefjg/1/) and it is working here

Comment: Hey I see the problem now. Your solution works. However I've realised that once I click on about section it scrolls, but when I click the about section again it doesn't work. I have to remove the # in the address bar then it works... Can you please tell me why? i.e. /DM8/index.html#  <--

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by OP It's working without javascript. We all should have been more clever about this, as anchors are common.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="clearfix">
   <div class="logo-container">
    <i><h2><b>DELIVERY MOTION</b></h2></i>

   </div>

   <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a id="delivery" href="#">Delivery</a></li>
    <li><a  id="about" href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>

   </ul>



   <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
  </nav>


    <div id="deliverySection">
  <h1> Order anything from anywhere in Karachi instantly at your doorstep. </h1><hr>
  <div id='fee-estimate-box'>
   <form id='fee-estimate-form' action="#">
     <legend id='delivery-text'>Delivery Fee Calculator</legend>
     <span>FROM </span> <input type="text" name="firstname" value="PICKUP ADDRESS">
     <span>TO </span> <input type="text" name="lastname" value="DROP ADDRESS">
     <span>ESTIMATED FEE </span> <input type="text" name="estimated-fee" value="0.00 PKR">
     <input class='btn-submit' type="submit" value="BOOK NOW!">
   </form>

  </div>
  <div id='silver-bar'>
   <img src='img/red-car.png' alt='fast deliver'>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="aboutSection">
  <h2> How it works </h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="infobox">
     <img src='img/map-icon.png' width="50px" height="50px">
     <h3> Search </h3>
     <h4>Select pickup address </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
     <br><br>
     <img src='img/arrow-up.png' width="50px" height="50px" class='arrows-img'>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"  id="infobox">
     <img src='img/delivery-icon.png' width="50px" height="50px" class="order-icon-img">
     <h3> Order</h3>
     <h4>Make a booking online </h4>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
     <br>
     <img src='img/arrow-down.png' width="50px" height="50px" class='arrows-img'>
      </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"  id="infobox">
     <img src='img/truck-icon.png' width="50px" height="50px">
     <h3> Delivered</h3>
     <h4>Instant courier delivery</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```